# Unsatisfiability of an Integer Programming Problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, integer-programming

Given a set of Diophantine equations of the form:

1. $(a_0A_0+a_1A_1+...a_nA_n)=c$
2. $c>0$

And all the remaining equations of the two form:

3. $a_i+a_j+..a_l=1$

where $a_1−a_n$, c are variables. And $A_1−A_n$ are constants.

Query: Does there exist a positive integer $c$, such that a non-negative integer solution to these equations does-not exist for that $c$?

I am aware the generic Integer Programming Problem (for satisfying argument) is NP-Complete. So, this in that sense, is the Dual to the problem. Thus, Is problem much simpler than the satisfiable case?

Answer (score 0):

If the $A$s have a common factor that $c$ does not there will be no solution

Comment: much thanks. As I understand if we pick a $c$ that has no common factor (which all A's do share) then it will be unsolvable. But, other than that special case, assuming we consider the generic case (where A's don't share a common factor),  is there any way to tell if we can have a c that is unsatisfiable?

Comment: Also if the $A$s are too disparate there will be no solution . Say there are five of them and they are $10^n$ and $c=5$

Comment: I understand. But, we have the freedom to choose any $c$ we wan't as long as it is positive and we need just 1 value of it that is unsatisfiable. So, do/can we have a generic approach to the problem?

Comment: One approach is by perhaps selecting a finite (and polynomial) number of c's (compared to the value of largest A) and at the end concluding its satisfiable or not (definitely)? Or perhaps another poly time algorithm?

Comment: Usually $c$ is given as part of the question, not selected as part of the solution.

Comment: I agree that in usual integer programming we are given a constant c which is to be satisfied. But, it our problem statement, we are asking if _any c exists that is unsatisfiable_. Its sort of the other way round. And I am unaware of the method to do so or its complexity.

Comment: There is always a $c$ for which it is satisfiable.  Just choose the $a$s as you wish and evaluate the first equation to find it.  That is not the question you asked.  It also seems all the $a$s have to be $0$ or $1$.  Did you mean that?  Please review your question and get it right.

Comment: Apologies, but 'any c exists that is **unsatisfiable**'. Yes, the a's which are part of the equations of the form in (3.) are 0 or 1. But not all.

Comment: That is what I answered.  I gave an example of $A$s and $c$ that is unsatisfiable.

Comment: I sincerely feel there is a misreading of the Q. For example given an instance of problem where A's do not share a common factor. The answer works for only cases where A's have a common factor. But, not when they don't. I hope i conveyed it clearly.

Comment: Several comments ago I gave an example without a common factor, the $A$s $1,10,100,1000,10000$ and $c=5$.  This did not depend on the $a$s being non-negative even.

Comment: I understand and agree. But, we are picking special cases or forms here as examples. My original question was for a generic method (if it exists) and its complexity not special case examples.

Comment: As long as all the $a$s are mentioned in at least one constraint equation, if $c$ is greater than the sum of the $A$s there will be no solution.  There will be at most $2^n\ c$s that have solutions because each $a$ must be $0,1$, so there will be lots of $c$s with no solution.